# PostgreSQL checking dates and raising errors

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `car_rental` of which I am trying to check each tuple for overlapping dates, and RAISE an EXCEPTION error if these values overlap with my `check_date` function. But no matter what I do, I keep getting a syntax error on the first line of my function. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_date(IN i_sdate DATE, IN i_edate DATE, IN i_plate varchar(10), OUT overlap) 
  SET @i_sdate = start_date(i_sdate);
  SET @i_edate = end_date(i_edate);
  SET @i_plate = plate(i_plate);
  BEGIN
  SET overlap = SELECT CASE WHEN (
      (@i_sdate BETWEEN  start_date AND end_date AND @i_plate = plate FROM car_rental)OR
      (@i_edate BETWEEN start_date AND end_date AND AND @i_plate = plate FROM car_rental)OR
      (start_date BETWEEN @i_sdate AND @i_edate AND AND @i_plate = plate )
      THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'unavailable --> %', plate
            USING HINT = 'Car is unavailable';
      )
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use MS SQL Server TSQL for PostgreSQL. Try to start [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html), continue [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc.html). PS If you mention an error - provide its text please.

Comment: @Abelisto . . .  This isn't quite SQL Server syntax.  I see elements of SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle, I think.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hmm... Yes, it will be interesting to know the origin of this code. However, as for me, `set @something = ...` is the sign of TSQL (but without semicolon as I remember).

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm new to SQL and I guess this is a result of mashing together 3 different SQL languages... I will start again from scratch using the documentation @Abelisto provided.

Comment: @AJP If you want to raise custom exception - [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) is your way. In particular, [about exceptions and others](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE). Good luck in your learning!

Comment: Cheers Abelisto, and thanks for not down voting that monstrosity! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with an [EXCLUDE constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html) and [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html). You don't need a procedural function or triggers.

```
CREATE TABLE car_rental (
  licplate   text,
  rentdates  daterange,
  PRIMARY KEY (licplate, rentdates),
  EXCLUDE USING gist (licplate WITH =, rentdates WITH &&)
);

INSERT INTO car_rental VALUES
  ('123abc', '[2017-01-05, 2017-01-15]'::daterange),
  ('123abc', '[2017-02-08, 2017-02-10]'::daterange);

INSERT INTO car_rental VALUES
  ('123abc', '[2017-01-10, 2017-01-12]'::daterange);
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "car_rental_licplate_rentdates_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (licplate, rentdates)=(123abc, [2017-01-10,2017-01-13)) conflicts with existing key (licplate, rentdates)=(123abc, [2017-01-05,2017-01-16)).
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I need to write this in a function, which I am having quite a bit of trouble understanding unfortunately.

Comment: It will be substantially slower, why would you want to do that? And, are you using `daterange`?